# AEM 5.6.1 to 6.3 or 6.5 migration

Tags: migration, aem

I am working on a migration of a website from AEM 5.6.1 to 6.3 or 6.5. I will have to do it using in-place upgrade. I tried to run test migration for a demo site Geometrix that was created by default on 5.6.1, without success. Here are the steps that I perform:

1. Set Java 7 as default
2. Run aem-5.6.1-author via java -jar
3. Check that Geometrix site is working.
4. Stop aem-5.6.1
5. Copy aem-6.3-quickstart.jar to the parent directory of the directory crx-quickstart
6. Set Java 8 as default
7. Unpack AEM-6.3 via “java -jar aem-6.3-quickstart.jar -unpack”
8. Run repository migration via “java -Xmx8192m -jar aem-6.3-quickstart.jar -v -x crx2oak -xargs -- --load-profile segment-fd”
9. Try to start AEM via
   “java -server -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dsling.run.modes=author,crx3,crx3tar -Djava.locale.providers=CLDR,JRE,SPI -jar crx-quickstart/app/cq-quickstart-6.3.0-standalone-quickstart.jar start -c crx-quickstart -i launchpad -p 4502 -Dsling.properties=conf/sling.properties”

I am receiving multiple errors on the console. The server does not work at all,
I cannot open login page or /system/console

Here are the logs:

```
27.07.2021 14:20:07.588 *INFO * [main] Starting launcher ...
27.07.2021 14:20:07.588 *INFO * [Apache Sling Control Listener@/127.0.0.1:62342] Apache Sling Control Listener started
27.07.2021 14:20:07.596 *INFO * [main] HTTP server port: 4502
27.07.2021 14:20:09.118 *ERROR* [FelixStartLevel] ERROR: Bundle '1' Error starting slinginstall:org.apache.sling.javax.activation-0.1.0.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.sling.javax.activation [1](R 1.0): missing requirement [org.apache.sling.javax.activation [1](R 1.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0)) Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.sling.javax.activation [1](R 1.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.sling.javax.activation [1](R 1.0): missing requirement [org.apache.sling.javax.activation [1](R 1.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0)) Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.sling.javax.activation [1](R 1.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4112)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2118)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1372)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
27.07.2021 14:20:09.120 *ERROR* [FelixStartLevel] ERROR: Bundle '2' Error starting slinginstall:slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve slf4j.api [2](R 2.1): missing requirement [slf4j.api [2](R 2.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0)) Unresolved requirements: [[slf4j.api [2](R 2.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve slf4j.api [2](R 2.1): missing requirement [slf4j.api [2](R 2.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0)) Unresolved requirements: [[slf4j.api [2](R 2.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4112)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2118)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1372)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
27.07.2021 14:20:09.122 *ERROR* [FelixStartLevel] ERROR: Bundle '3' Error starting slinginstall:org.apache.sling.settings-1.2.2.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.sling.settings [3](R 3.1): missing requirement [org.apache.sling.settings [3](R 3.1)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j)(version>=1.5.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve slf4j.api [2](R 2.1): missing requirement [slf4j.api [2](R 2.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))] Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.sling.settings [3](R 3.1)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j)(version>=1.5.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.sling.settings [3](R 3.1): missing requirement [org.apache.sling.settings [3](R 3.1)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j)(version>=1.5.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve slf4j.api [2](R 2.1): missing requirement [slf4j.api [2](R 2.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))] Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.sling.settings [3](R 3.1)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j)(version>=1.5.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4112)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2118)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1372)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
27.07.2021 14:20:09.124 *ERROR* [FelixStartLevel] ERROR: Bundle '4' Error starting slinginstall:jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.4.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve jcl.over.slf4j [4](R 4.1): missing requirement [jcl.over.slf4j [4](R 4.1)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j.spi)(version>=1.7.21)) [caused by: Unable to resolve slf4j.api [2](R 2.1): missing requirement [slf4j.api [2](R 2.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))] Unresolved requirements: [[jcl.over.slf4j [4](R 4.1)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j.spi)(version>=1.7.21))])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve jcl.over.slf4j [4](R 4.1): missing requirement [jcl.over.slf4j [4](R 4.1)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j.spi)(version>=1.7.21)) [caused by: Unable to resolve slf4j.api [2](R 2.1): missing requirement [slf4j.api [2](R 2.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))] Unresolved requirements: [[jcl.over.slf4j [4](R 4.1)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j.spi)(version>=1.7.21))]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4112)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2118)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1372)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
27.07.2021 14:20:09.125 *ERROR* [FelixStartLevel] ERROR: Bundle '5' Error starting slinginstall:org.apache.sling.commons.logservice-1.0.2.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.sling.commons.logservice [5](R 5.1): missing requirement [org.apache.sling.commons.logservice [5](R 5.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6)) Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.sling.commons.logservice [5](R 5.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6))])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.sling.commons.logservice [5](R 5.1): missing requirement [org.apache.sling.commons.logservice [5](R 5.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6)) Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.sling.commons.logservice [5](R 5.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6))]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4112)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2118)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1372)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
27.07.2021 14:20:09.131 *ERROR* [FelixStartLevel] ERROR: Bundle '6' Error starting slinginstall:org.apache.sling.installer.provider.file-1.0.2.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.sling.installer.provider.file [6](R 6.1): missing requirement [org.apache.sling.installer.provider.file [6](R 6.1)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j)(version>=1.5.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve slf4j.api [2](R 2.1): missing requirement [slf4j.api [2](R 2.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))] Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.sling.installer.provider.file [6](R 6.1)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j)(version>=1.5.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.sling.installer.provider.file [6](R 6.1): missing requirement [org.apache.sling.installer.provider.file [6](R 6.1)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j)(version>=1.5.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve slf4j.api [2](R 2.1): missing requirement [slf4j.api [2](R 2.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))] Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.sling.installer.provider.file [6](R 6.1)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j)(version>=1.5.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4112)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2118)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1372)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
27.07.2021 14:20:09.134 *ERROR* [FelixStartLevel] ERROR: Bundle '7' Error starting slinginstall:org.apache.sling.installer.core-3.4.6.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.sling.installer.core [7](R 7.1): missing requirement [org.apache.sling.installer.core [7](R 7.1)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j)(version>=1.7.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve slf4j.api [2](R 2.1): missing requirement [slf4j.api [2](R 2.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))] Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.sling.installer.core [7](R 7.1)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j)(version>=1.7.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.sling.installer.core [7](R 7.1): missing requirement [org.apache.sling.installer.core [7](R 7.1)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j)(version>=1.7.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve slf4j.api [2](R 2.1): missing requirement [slf4j.api [2](R 2.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))] Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.sling.installer.core [7](R 7.1)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j)(version>=1.7.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4112)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2118)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1372)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
27.07.2021 14:20:09.135 *ERROR* [FelixStartLevel] ERROR: Bundle '9' Error starting slinginstall:log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.4.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve log4j.over.slf4j [9](R 9.1): missing requirement [log4j.over.slf4j [9](R 9.1)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j.helpers)(version>=1.6.0)) [caused by: Unable to resolve slf4j.api [2](R 2.1): missing requirement [slf4j.api [2](R 2.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))] Unresolved requirements: [[log4j.over.slf4j [9](R 9.1)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j.helpers)(version>=1.6.0))])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve log4j.over.slf4j [9](R 9.1): missing requirement [log4j.over.slf4j [9](R 9.1)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j.helpers)(version>=1.6.0)) [caused by: Unable to resolve slf4j.api [2](R 2.1): missing requirement [slf4j.api [2](R 2.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))] Unresolved requirements: [[log4j.over.slf4j [9](R 9.1)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j.helpers)(version>=1.6.0))]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4112)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2118)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1372)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
27.07.2021 14:20:09.140 *ERROR* [FelixStartLevel] ERROR: Bundle '11' Error starting slinginstall:org.apache.sling.commons.log-3.0.0.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.sling.commons.log [11](R 11.1): missing requirement [org.apache.sling.commons.log [11](R 11.1)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j.event)(version>=1.7.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve slf4j.api [2](R 2.1): missing requirement [slf4j.api [2](R 2.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))] Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.sling.commons.log [11](R 11.1)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j.event)(version>=1.7.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.sling.commons.log [11](R 11.1): missing requirement [org.apache.sling.commons.log [11](R 11.1)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j.event)(version>=1.7.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve slf4j.api [2](R 2.1): missing requirement [slf4j.api [2](R 2.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))] Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.sling.commons.log [11](R 11.1)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j.event)(version>=1.7.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4112)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2118)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1372)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
27.07.2021 14:20:09.145 *ERROR* [FelixStartLevel] ERROR: Bundle '13' Error starting slinginstall:org.apache.sling.launchpad.installer-1.2.0.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.sling.launchpad.installer [13](R 13.1): missing requirement [org.apache.sling.launchpad.installer [13](R 13.1)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j)(version>=1.5.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve slf4j.api [2](R 2.1): missing requirement [slf4j.api [2](R 2.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))] Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.sling.launchpad.installer [13](R 13.1)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j)(version>=1.5.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.sling.launchpad.installer [13](R 13.1): missing requirement [org.apache.sling.launchpad.installer [13](R 13.1)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j)(version>=1.5.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve slf4j.api [2](R 2.1): missing requirement [slf4j.api [2](R 2.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))] Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.sling.launchpad.installer [13](R 13.1)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j)(version>=1.5.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4112)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2118)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1372)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
27.07.2021 14:20:09.148 *ERROR* [FelixStartLevel] ERROR: Bundle '14' Error starting slinginstall:com.adobe.granite.startup-0.6.2.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve com.adobe.granite.startup [14](R 14.0): missing requirement [com.adobe.granite.startup [14](R 14.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j)(version>=1.5.2)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve slf4j.api [2](R 2.1): missing requirement [slf4j.api [2](R 2.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))] Unresolved requirements: [[com.adobe.granite.startup [14](R 14.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j)(version>=1.5.2)(!(version>=2.0.0)))])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve com.adobe.granite.startup [14](R 14.0): missing requirement [com.adobe.granite.startup [14](R 14.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j)(version>=1.5.2)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve slf4j.api [2](R 2.1): missing requirement [slf4j.api [2](R 2.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))] Unresolved requirements: [[com.adobe.granite.startup [14](R 14.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j)(version>=1.5.2)(!(version>=2.0.0)))]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4112)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2118)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1372)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
27.07.2021 14:20:09.150 *ERROR* [FelixStartLevel] ERROR: Bundle '19' Error starting launchpad:resources/install/2/org.apache.aries.util-1.0.0.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.aries.util [19](R 19.1): missing requirement [org.apache.aries.util [19](R 19.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6)) Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.aries.util [19](R 19.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6))])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.aries.util [19](R 19.1): missing requirement [org.apache.aries.util [19](R 19.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6)) Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.aries.util [19](R 19.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6))]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4112)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2118)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1372)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
27.07.2021 14:20:09.151 *ERROR* [FelixStartLevel] ERROR: Bundle '23' Error starting launchpad:resources/install/5/commons-io-2.4.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.commons.io [23](R 23.1): missing requirement [org.apache.commons.io [23](R 23.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6)) Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.commons.io [23](R 23.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6))])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.commons.io [23](R 23.1): missing requirement [org.apache.commons.io [23](R 23.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6)) Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.commons.io [23](R 23.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6))]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4112)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2118)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1372)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
27.07.2021 14:20:09.154 *ERROR* [FelixStartLevel] ERROR: Bundle '36' Error starting launchpad:resources/install/5/org.apache.sling.installer.factory.configuration-1.0.10.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.sling.installer.factory.configuration [36](R 36.1): missing requirement [org.apache.sling.installer.factory.configuration [36](R 36.1)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j)(version>=1.5.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve slf4j.api [2](R 2.1): missing requirement [slf4j.api [2](R 2.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))] Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.sling.installer.factory.configuration [36](R 36.1)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j)(version>=1.5.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.sling.installer.factory.configuration [36](R 36.1): missing requirement [org.apache.sling.installer.factory.configuration [36](R 36.1)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j)(version>=1.5.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve slf4j.api [2](R 2.1): missing requirement [slf4j.api [2](R 2.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))] Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.sling.installer.factory.configuration [36](R 36.1)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j)(version>=1.5.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4112)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2118)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1372)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
27.07.2021 14:20:09.156 *ERROR* [FelixStartLevel] ERROR: Bundle '44' Error starting launchpad:resources/install/9/org.apache.felix.configadmin-1.6.1-R1411640.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.configadmin [44](R 44.1): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.configadmin [44](R 44.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6)) Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.felix.configadmin [44](R 44.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6))])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.configadmin [44](R 44.1): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.configadmin [44](R 44.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6)) Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.felix.configadmin [44](R 44.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6))]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4112)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2118)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1372)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
27.07.2021 14:20:09.158 *ERROR* [FelixStartLevel] ERROR: Bundle '92' Error starting launchpad:resources/install/0/com.adobe.granite.crypto-0.0.24.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve com.adobe.granite.crypto [92](R 92.1): missing requirement [com.adobe.granite.crypto [92](R 92.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7)) Unresolved requirements: [[com.adobe.granite.crypto [92](R 92.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve com.adobe.granite.crypto [92](R 92.1): missing requirement [com.adobe.granite.crypto [92](R 92.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7)) Unresolved requirements: [[com.adobe.granite.crypto [92](R 92.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))]
27.07.2021 14:20:09.159 *ERROR* [FelixStartLevel] ERROR: Bundle '308' Error starting slinginstall:org.apache.felix.coordinator-1.0.2.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.coordinator [308](R 308.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.coordinator [308](R 308.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5)) Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.felix.coordinator [308](R 308.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5))])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.coordinator [308](R 308.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.coordinator [308](R 308.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5)) Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.felix.coordinator [308](R 308.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5))]
27.07.2021 14:20:09.168 *INFO * [main] Startup completed
27.07.2021 14:20:11.184 *ERROR* [FelixStartLevel] ERROR: Bundle '16' Error starting launchpad:resources/install/2/org.apache.aries.jmx.core-1.0.1.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.aries.jmx.core [16](R 16.0): missing requirement [org.apache.aries.jmx.core [16](R 16.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.log)(version>=1.3.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.sling.commons.logservice [5](R 5.1): missing requirement [org.apache.sling.commons.logservice [5](R 5.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6))] Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.aries.jmx.core [16](R 16.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.log)(version>=1.3.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.aries.jmx.core [16](R 16.0): missing requirement [org.apache.aries.jmx.core [16](R 16.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.log)(version>=1.3.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.sling.commons.logservice [5](R 5.1): missing requirement [org.apache.sling.commons.logservice [5](R 5.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6))] Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.aries.jmx.core [16](R 16.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.log)(version>=1.3.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))]
27.07.2021 14:20:11.186 *ERROR* [FelixStartLevel] ERROR: Bundle '17' Error starting launchpad:resources/install/2/org.apache.aries.jmx.whiteboard-1.0.0.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.aries.jmx.whiteboard [17](R 17.0): missing requirement [org.apache.aries.jmx.whiteboard [17](R 17.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j)(version>=1.5.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve slf4j.api [2](R 2.1): missing requirement [slf4j.api [2](R 2.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))] Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.aries.jmx.whiteboard [17](R 17.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j)(version>=1.5.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.aries.jmx.whiteboard [17](R 17.0): missing requirement [org.apache.aries.jmx.whiteboard [17](R 17.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j)(version>=1.5.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve slf4j.api [2](R 2.1): missing requirement [slf4j.api [2](R 2.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))] Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.aries.jmx.whiteboard [17](R 17.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j)(version>=1.5.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))]
27.07.2021 14:20:11.187 *ERROR* [FelixStartLevel] ERROR: Bundle '18' Error starting launchpad:resources/install/2/org.apache.aries.transaction.manager-1.0.1.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.aries.transaction.manager [18](R 18.0): missing requirement [org.apache.aries.transaction.manager [18](R 18.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.aries.util.nls)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.aries.util [19](R 19.1): missing requirement [org.apache.aries.util [19](R 19.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6))] Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.aries.transaction.manager [18](R 18.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.aries.util.nls)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.aries.transaction.manager [18](R 18.0): missing requirement [org.apache.aries.transaction.manager [18](R 18.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.aries.util.nls)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.aries.util [19](R 19.1): missing requirement [org.apache.aries.util [19](R 19.1)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6))] Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.aries.transaction.manager [18](R 18.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.aries.util.nls)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))]

27.07.2021 14:20:11.187 *ERROR* [FelixStartLevel] ERROR: Bundle '20' Error starting launchpad:resources/install/2/org.apache.sling.discovery.api-0.1.0-R1484784.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.sling.discovery.api [20](R 20.0): missing requirement [org.apache.sling.discovery.api [20](R 20.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0)) Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.sling.discovery.api [20](R 20.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.sling.discovery.api [20](R 20.0): missing requirement [org.apache.sling.discovery.api [20](R 20.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0)) Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.sling.discovery.api [20](R 20.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))]
```

I tried the same steps for 6.5 with the same result: the server does not work.

Could anyone share a script or a detailed list of migration steps? Official AEM documentation is vague.

Comment: What did you do in the end? Did you solve this particular issue?

Answer (score 0):

For such an old migration, I suggest migrating via packaging the content and install it via package manager or putting the package inside `crx-quickstart/install` directory. Of course, if the site is too big, the package way will have its challenges.

Regarding the code, the best is to create a new project with a recent archetype and moving the code piece by piece.

Answer (score 0):

For migration to AEM new version, it would be good to create project using recent maven archetype then add your existing code to new project and fix require changes.
For content- create package from old AEM version and upload it to new AEM instance via packmanager.

Answer (score 0):

After migration to 6.5 I had this issue with bundles.
Try to replace conf/sling.properties file from other working environment.
Of cause make backup before.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).